# How to enable a combo list to be edited in a form?

Tags: ms-access

I have 1-to-1 relation between `Supplier` and `Country` tables. I need to create a form so I can edit all the fields of `Supplier` and `Country` tables. So far it's possible to edit all fields of `Supplier` but there is only a option list of countries I can select from (but not add one).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Comment: what do you expect from the option list ?

Comment: Surely his relationships are wrong?

Comment: MS Access 2010. I expect to directly enter a value into combo box and be able to save it without opening another form or table (to add country). Why wrong?

Comment: country.id should relate to supplier.countryID, not supplier.ID or supplier.country

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with it by setting the Limit To List property to "No", and then maybe checking the field to see if it exists in the Country table and, if not, adding it before you continue processing the form.  A bit unorthodox, but do-able.